# CLLocationDistance Addition

Tags: iphone, objective-c

There are multiple questions regarding how to calculate CLLocationDistance (which is super easy with `newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation:`), but no one has asked how to add up multiple distances.

If I try to add up and total my distances with totalDistance += newDistance I get "Invalid operands to binary expression. I can't seem to add a type double to my strong number. How do I convert CLLocationDistance to a decimal or float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that what I needed to keep a tally on total distance was to convert the double into an NSNumber and back into a double, like so:

```
numberThatIsSotred = [ NSNumber numberWithDouble:coordinate ];
theDobuleINeed = numberThatIsStored.doubleValue ;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code compiles and executes fine for me:

```
    CLLocationDistance total=0.0;
    CLLocationDistance loc1 = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];
    CLLocationDistance loc2 = [oldLocation distanceFromLocation:newLocation];
    NSLog(@" loc1 = %f, loc2=%f", loc1, loc2);

    total += loc1;
    total += loc2;

    NSLog(@" total=%f", total);
```

What does your code look like?  How are you declaring your "strong" number?

Comment: That's what my code looks like as well, the problem is surely the way I'm declaring the strong number: @property ( nonatomic , strong ) NSNumber *totalDistance ;

Comment: `NSNumber` is an object type and does not respond to normal arithmetic expressions. CLLocationDistance is probably just a typedef for float or double. You can check the NSNumber documents for how to convert to/from primitive number types.

Comment: CLLocationDistance is indeed a typedef double.  I suggest you declare your strong variable to be a CLLocationDistance rather than an NSNumber.  If you need an NSNumber later on, once you have the total, you can easily create one like this:  NSNumber *myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: _theTotalDistance];

Comment: Alright I've declared the variable to be a CLLocationDistance. total += newDistance ; is still giving me "invalid operands to binary expression ( CLLocationDistance (aka double) and CLLocation Distance (aka double))

Comment: Just declare your variable as CLLocationDistance total; without the asterisk. That works fine on me.